# BrowserAuthError: interaction_in_progress. Microsoft Azure Active Directory

Tags: reactjs, azure, azure-active-directory

When I try to invoke signin on the production website using Microsoft Azure AD I get a `BrowserAuthError: Interaction is currently in progress`. I can't for the life of me figure out what I did wrong. It's the same piece of code I'm using for production that I'm using for staging and development. The only difference is the change in config for the `clientId`, `redirecturl`, and `postLogoutRedirectUri`. I don't experience this on localhost, or staging.

I've followed the solutions in the docs up to a certain extent but it still doesn't work. Here's my current codebase

```
const LoginLayout = () => {
    const navigate = useNavigate();
    const { instance, accounts, inProgress } = useMsal();
    const account = useAccount(accounts[0] || {});
    const auth_token = useSelector(state => state.auth);
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const isAuthenticated = useIsAuthenticated();

    console.log(auth_token.token);

    const handleLogin = async () => {
        if (!isAuthenticated && inProgress === InteractionStatus.None) {
            await instance.loginRedirect();
        }
    }

  useEffect(() => {
    if (account) {
        instance.acquireTokenSilent({
            scopes: config.azure.auth.scopes,
            account: account
        }).then((response) => {
            if(response) {
                //console.log("hi "+accounts.length);
                const authToken = response.accessToken;
                console.log(authToken);
                dispatch(setToken(authToken));
            }
        });

        if (accounts.length > 0){
            navigate("/overview");
        }
    }
   }, [account, instance]);


  return (
    <>
        <div className="block w-full">
            {
                accounts.length > 0 ? null
                : inProgress === "login" ? 
                <button 
                    type="submit" 
                    disabled 
                    onClick={handleLogin}    
                >
                    <p>Login</p>
                    <h1><IoSyncOutline className="text-xl animate-spin" /></h1>
                </button> 
                : <button 
                    type="submit" 
                    onClick={handleLogin}    
                >
                    <p>Login</p>
                    <h1><IoArrowForward className='text-xl' /></h1>
                </button> 
            }
        </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

Below is the azure AD config `config.azure` for production. If it's worth noting, I was given the same ID to use as client and tenant ID for the production config

```
const azureAD = {
    auth: {
        clientId: "507772e4-",
        redirecturl: ["https://usmartinvoiceadmin.example.net"],
        postLogoutRedirectUri: "https://usmartinvoiceadmin.example.net",
        scopes: [
            "api://db7641cc-/access_as_user"
        ],
        authority: "https://login.microsoftonline.com/507772e4-"
    },
    cache: {
        cacheLocation: 'sessionStorage',
        storeAuthStateInCookie: true,
    },
}
```

I'd really appreciate any help

Answer (score 1):

- The error message `BrowserAuthError: interaction_in_progress. Microsoft Azure Active Directory` means that another interactive Azure Active Directory (AAD) authentication flow is already in progress.
- This can happen if you have multiple Azure AD applications open in the same browser, or if you are trying to authenticate to Azure AD from within another interactive flow
- To Resolve this you need to check if there is an ongoing interaction and if there are no accounts logged in. If both of these conditions are met, then the code starts a login redirect.
- This will ensure that only one interactive authentication flow is running at a time.

Here is the code that i used  to resolve and to able to login without any error

```
import  React  from  'react';
import { useMsal } from  '@azure/msal-react';
import { InteractionStatus } from  "@azure/msal-browser";

function  AuthButton() {

const { instance, accounts, inProgress, isAuthenticated } =  useMsal(); 

const  login  =  async () => {
if (!isAuthenticated  &&  inProgress  ===  InteractionStatus.None  &&  accounts.length  ===  0) {
await  instance.loginPopup();
}
};

const  logout  = () => {
instance.logoutPopup();
};

return (
<div>
{accounts.length === 0 ? (
<button  onClick={login}>Login</button>
) : (
<button  onClick={logout}>Logout</button>
)}
</div>
);
}
export  default  AuthButton;
```

**Start the Development Server**

```
npm start
```

**Result**
[image]

[image]

[image]